# WooCommerce Product Sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, woocommerce

So i've edited the sidebar widget "Products" so it includes the Product images under the title/price etc shown here in this picture: http://puu.sh/k6oLe/7106e58f69.jpg

But when i add the code to make it a clickable link it removes the first image and only shows 2nd 3rd and 4th images.
As shown here: http://puu.sh/k6oHD/3455e7674c.jpg

Here's the code:

```
    <?php global $product; ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">
        <?php echo $product->get_image(); ?>
        <span class="product-title"><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?></span>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) echo $product->get_rating_html(); ?>
    <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
    </a>
    <a><br>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>"
    <?php global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
    {
    echo $image_link = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id );
    }
    ?>
</li>
```

Whenever i add this line:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>"
```

it removed the first image.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure it's not being hidden with CSS or JS? If you inspect the source, is the first image shown in the source code?

Comment: Hmm the image is there when i inspect it: http://puu.sh/k6phY/634f995355.png
So the Hoodie is the one which is hidden and that's the one which the href is wrapped around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have sorted the problem now with an eye opener from @mevius to double check my work!
I added the title= at the end of the href:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" title="Variations">
<?php global $product;
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
echo $image_link = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id );
}
?>
</a>
```